# android や iPhone で、今触っているアプリはただ一つですが、それを特定のアプリに切り替える操作を何といいますか？

Tags: android, iphone, 専門用語

いまいち表現がわからないので質問します。

iPhone や Android では、アプリは複数起動していて、その中で一つだけが操作対象になっているかと思っています。

例えば iPhone では、スクリーンを画面下端から上にスワイプすると起動中アプリ一覧が表示され、その中から選択することで、操作対象のアプリを切り替えることができると思いますが、この動作は何といいますか？

仕様を書いたり、ドキュメントで調べたりするために使いたいな、と思い質問しています。

Answer (score 2):

Android の場合は単純に **タスクの切り替え** かなと思います。(より細かく表現するならアクティビティ？)

[タスクとバックスタック  |  Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html?hl=ja)

> この時点で、ユーザーはホームに移動してタスク B を開始したアプリケーションを選択して
> (またはオーバービュー画面でアプリのタスクを選択して) タスク B に切り替えることもできます。
> これは、Android のマルチタスク操作の一例です。

Answer (score 1):

iOSはタスクスイッチャーやAppスイッチャーなどを使います。

公式サポートのページに書かれている用語ではAppスイッチャーと書かれているので、最近はAppスイッチャーというのではないでしょうか。

> 画面下部の中央から上にスワイプし、そのまましばらく指を放さず、App スイッチャーが表示されたら放します。

https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT202070